# VueJs - Table pagination and filter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `Vue2.js` and `Element UI` as a framework. I would like to be able to **filter** a table which is **sliced**. To do so, I use the `table` and `filter` components whose documentation could be found [here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table).

### Situation OK

The table is not sliced. When you picked a filter, a loop goes trough each row and check if the value of the column is equal to the filter.

### Situation NOT OK

The table is sliced. When you picked a filter, a loop goes trough each row that results of the slice and check if the value of the column is equal to the filter. By doing that we don't filter the "hidden" values.

I've made a little https://jsfiddle.net/acm3q6q8/3/ so it is easier to understand.

All of this make sense since I'm not working on the whole data, but on a sliced version.

One solution could be to hide rows instead of excluding them by slicing the data, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution ?

### What I want to achieve

- In the `jsfiddle`, display only 2 items.
- Filter the `tag` to display only rows whose tag is `Office`

#### Actual result

There is no row displayed since the row whose `tag` was office was not part of the sliced table.

#### Expected result

When filtering, I would like to take into account rows that are not necessarily displayed.

#### Important

This should work fine with a multiple filter (ie I select several tags)

#### EDIT

In the same extent if you want to sort the name by alphabetical order, Albert won't be displayed if you displayed only 2 items.

Comment: The tag filter doesn't appear to work on that fiddle.

Comment: Yes it does. If you have all items displayed everything's fine. As soon as you start to slice the table, it filters only on the sliced table and not the whole one.

Comment: I mean, when I pick a tag, nothing happens. `filterTag` is never called.

Comment: It does work on my side. I added a `console.log` in `filterTag`. Could you check again ?

Comment: Tag is fine, you should just `Confirm` "Office" selection in order to filter rows (click left chineese word under tag selection).

Comment: @wostex thanks, that's what I was missing. Had no idea that was a confirmation.

Comment: Sliced rows are not hidden, they are excluded. The filter will never see them.

Comment: @RoyJ I know that, I rephrase what I said : One solution could be to hide rows instead of excluding them by slicing the data, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution ?

Comment: You want to apply the filter first, and then the slice, but I don't think the table widget gives you that ability.

Comment: That's what I think too. I could to it but I would need to implement my own `filter component`. That's what you meant also ?

Comment: The table component gives you a `filter-change` event with the selected filters. You have to handle it yourself. Here is an example. https://jsfiddle.net/nd9xt07x/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the `filter-change` event on the table component (documented [here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table)), and filter/slice yourself.

```
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        numberItemToShow : 4,
        tableData: [...],
        filter: []
      }

    },
    computed : {
      filterData() {
          if (!this.filter.length)
            return this.tableData.slice(0, this.numberItemToShow)
          else
            return this.tableData
              .filter(row => this.filter.includes(row.tag))
              .slice(0, this.numberItemToShow);
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onFilterChange(filters){
        if (filters.tag)
            this.filter = filters.tag;
      }
    }  
}
```

And the template

```
<template>
<input v-model="numberItemToShow" placeholder="edit me">
<p>Number of item to display: {{ numberItemToShow }}</p>
  <el-table ref="tab" :data="filterData" border style="width: 100%" @filter-change="onFilterChange">
    <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name"   sortable>
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="tag" label="Tag" column-key="tag" :filters="[{ text: 'Home', value: 'Home' }, { text: 'Office', value: 'Office' }]">
      <template scope="scope">
        <el-tag :type="scope.row.tag === 'Home' ? 'primary' : 'success'" close-transition>{{scope.row.tag}}</el-tag>
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
</template>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yw18so9z/1/).

Comment: There is a weird bug though. Open your example. Change the number of item to `2`. Activate the `Office tag filter` and click on the arrow to sort the name.

Comment: @Leo I don't have an explanation for that. It seems like the component is using some cached data somehow. Here is a fix though. It listens to the `sort-change` event and forces the computed to update. https://jsfiddle.net/yw18so9z/3/

Comment: I tried the new fiddle, but the issue is still present.

Comment: Works great. Thank you. I have one last question, cause I noticed another issue. https://jsfiddle.net/7t8o249g/. If you want to sort by age and if you display only two items. The sort will be made among these two items instead of the whole data. How can I deal with that and apply the sort on the whole data table instead of what is displayed ?

Comment: @Leo because of your desire to limit the rows the way you want, essentially you have to manage several of the things the control was giving to you (it seems odd it doesn't give you the ability to limit rows displayed, but whatever). That being the case, you have to handle the sorting as well. They seem to have a control for pagination, but it doesn't seem to integrate into the table control at all. Anyway, here is an updated fiddle that handles sorting. https://jsfiddle.net/7t8o249g/1/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the slicing is done before the filtering. The filter has to see the original data, and the row-counting must be part of the filtering.

Since the filter looks at one row at a time, keeping track of the matched rows is a little tricky. What I did here is keep a counter of matched rows that resets to zero when the row being looked at is the first row of data. This is hacky, but it works. There may be a better way; I am not familiar with the table widget.

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
       numberItemToShow : 4,
        tableData: [{
          name: 'One',
          tag: 'Home'
        }, {
          name: 'Two',
          tag: 'Home'
        }, {
          name: 'Three',
          tag: 'Home'
        }, {
          name: 'Four',
          tag: 'Office'
        }],
        scratchCounter: 0
      }
    },
    methods: {
      filterTag(value, row) {
        const matched = row.tag === value;

        if (row === this.tableData[0]) {
         this.scratchCounter = 0;
        }
        if (matched) {
         ++this.scratchCounter;
        }
        return this.scratchCounter <= this.numberItemToShow && matched;
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-default/index.css");
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<template>
<input v-model="numberItemToShow" placeholder="edit me">
<p>Number of item to display: {{ numberItemToShow }}</p>
  <el-table :data="tableData" border style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column prop="name" label="Name">
    </el-table-column>
    <el-table-column prop="tag" label="Tag" :filters="[{ text: 'Home', value: 'Home' }, { text: 'Office', value: 'Office' }]" :filter-method="filterTag">
      <template scope="scope">
        <el-tag :type="scope.row.tag === 'Home' ? 'primary' : 'success'" close-transition>{{scope.row.tag}}</el-tag>
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
</template>
</div>
```